# How to compute the $2n^{\text{th}}$-order derivative of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the function `f[x_]=x^5`. The first-order derivative of this function is given by `D[f[x],{x,1}]`. More generally, we can compute the $n^{\text{th}}$-order derivative (where $n$ is finite) by writing `D[f[x],{x,n}]`.

My question is, how do we compute the $2n^{\text{th}}$-order derivative? That is, how do we find the zeroth-order derivative (n=0), second-order derivative (n=1), fourth-order derivative (n=2) etc? The command `D[f[x],{x,2n}]` does not seem to be recognized.

Comment: Here is a workaround `D[f[x], {x, m}] /. m -> (2*n)`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your response. What does `/.` do exactly?

Comment: It just replaces `m` by `2 n` in the result. Mathematica does not like the order of derivative to be something other than length 1. i.e atomic.  May be by design. I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this using `HoldForm` and `ReleaseHold`:

```
ReleaseHold@D[f[x], {x, HoldForm[2 m]}]
```

[image]

With `f[x_] := x^5`:

```
 ReleaseHold@D[f[x], {x, HoldForm[2 m]}]

 (*x^(5 - 2 m) FactorialPower[5, 2 m]*)
```

Taking $m=1$ and $m=2$:

```
% /. m -> # & /@ Range[2]

(*{20 x^3, 120 x}*)
```